# Breakpoint when HTML element is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, debugging

Is it possible, in Chrome/Firefox, or some other tool, to set a breakpoint on an HTML element, such as a `<div>` or `<li>` to see which javascript/jquery function is populating content inside that element on page load?

Comment: a page load creates the native html elements... then you may call a js script to created dynamic elements , so you need to insert the break point into your js script that creates those dynamic elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firebug, you can right-click an element in the DOM view and select "Break when child inserted" or "Break when attribute changed".

Comment: Chrome's dev tools has the same thing: right click on an element and choose when to break from the "break on" submenu.